# How to remove folder from Request_URI in php and xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, uri, request-uri

I have url to index.php like this
`http://localhost/exercise/`

When I call

```
return var_dump(
     trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/')
);
```

I have `exercise` project folder in xampp's htdocs.

On url `http://localhost/exercise/sd/ds` I get `exercise/sd/ds`

How to get rid of that folder name in request_uri? Or any other (if there would be) folders if this php script was nested in some many folders.

How to get Request_URI started from this point where script is?

Comment: Your script is located at `host/exercise` and you want to get `/math/lesson1` when `host/exercise/math/lesson1` is requested?

Comment: I want just to have URI returned by REQUEST_URI to be `page` when I am on `host/exercise/page`, not `exercise/page`

Answer (score 0):

After your comment, you can use a .htacces-file to resolved your problem. The .htaccess have to locate in the same folder as your script.

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* /exercise/index.php?url=%1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

index.php:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

Comment: This is bad solution for this and doesn't solve this particular problem. e.g. on `http://localhost/exercise/sd/ds` where script is in `http://localhost/exercise/` and it is index.php URI string for `http://localhost/exercise/sd/ds` should be `sd/ds`, but with your solution it will be only `ds`

Comment: I still get the folder name, e.g. for index page `/exercise/` and for `localhost/exercise/brrrr` page got `/exercise/brrrr`